# How to print specified pattern in Java

Tags: java

I want to print the below pattern

```
   v
  v v
 v   v
v     v
```

Below is the code which I have tried.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("The Pattern is");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        //System.out.println(i);
        for (int k = 0; k <= i - 2; k++) {
            System.out.print("v ");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j <= 4 - i; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();  
    }
}
```

I'm getting the below output:

```
v
v v
```

Can anyone help me to solve this pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Move the j loop before k loop

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
 System.out.println("The Pattern is");

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {

     for(int j=0;j<=4-i;j++)
       System.out.print(" ");

     for(int k=0;k<=i-2;k++) 
       System.out.print("V ");

     System.out.println();  
 }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/Tx2x31)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do the job (dynamic number of rows):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int numRows = 4;
    for (int row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
        for (int preSpace = numRows - row; preSpace >= 0; preSpace--) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        if (row > 0) {
            System.out.print("v");
            for (int postSpace = 1; postSpace < row * 2; postSpace++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("v");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will print it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("The Pattern is");

    // startup parameter
    final int rowSize = 4;
    final int startPos = 2;

    int leftPos = startPos;
    int rightPos = startPos;

    // for each row
    for(int row=0; row<rowSize; row++){
        // find and print v (max is right most v)
        for(int col=0; col<rightPos+1; col++){

            // when reach left pos
            if(col==leftPos){
                System.out.print("v");
                // when left pos and right pos is same
                if(leftPos==rightPos){
                    break;
                }
            }

            // when reach right pos
            if (col==rightPos){
                System.out.print("v");
                break;
            }

            // print space when it is not match
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        // next line
        System.out.println();

        // adjust position
        if(leftPos!=0) leftPos--;
        rightPos++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
public class DrawPattern {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, j;
        int num = 7;
        for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < num; j++) {
                if (isConditionMatch(num, i, j)) {
                    System.out.print("V");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    // this pattern will decide where to print 'V'
    private static boolean isConditionMatch(int num, int i, int j) {
        return (i + j == (num - 1) / 2 || j - i == (num - 1) / 2);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
   V   
  V V  
 V   V 
V     V
```